# What does "get a spot" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was registering a user account online at a sports club and got an Error Prompt saying "Can we get a spot"? See my picture below.

I know "spot" has the meaning of dirt, location, but cannot figure out what is the meaning of the sentence in the context. Can anybody help?
[image]

Comment: It means nothing to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a gym, to "spot" for someone means to help them with heavy weights - either to get them into a starting position, or to be ready in case the weight slips so that they don't hurt themselves.

From [wiktionary, definition 12:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spot#English)

> (*gymnastics, dance, weightlifting*) One who spots (supports or assists a maneuver, or is prepared to assist if safety dictates); a spotter.

In this case, they are making a joke with their 404 page.  "Can we get a spot" means "Something went wrong and we need help".